# How To Verify that a List/Field is not empty?

Tags: exception, null, empty

These are the methods I use to check if a field is empty:

```
p.Call_Summary__c != null 
p.Call_Summary__c!=''
```

And these are the methods to check that a list isn't empty:

```
CClist != null 
CClist.isEmpty()!=null
```

Do you recommend on anything else? 
What's the difference between '`isEmpty`' to '`!=null`'?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists the difference is that

```
CClist != null
```

Checks if you declared the list. You can't use isEmpty() on a non-declared list - it'll throw you an Exception.

```
CClist.isEmpty()!=null
```

Will always return true(if list is declared), because it shows whether or not list has elements and will never return null. It always returns either true or false.
In order to check if list has elements you need to check both:

```
if (CClist != null && !CClist.isEmpty())
```

Or

```
if (CClist != null && !CCList.size() >0)
```

Comment: Is there a difference between '!CClist.isEmpty()' to 'CCList.size() >0' ?

Comment: @Barracks no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

`isEmpty` returns true or false so in your example if it was empty or not it would evaluate to true.

```
CClist.isEmpty()!=null
```

string fields you can use `string.isBlank` or `string.isNotBlank`

For lists and sets you can use

`set.isEmpty()` which returns true if it is or false if it is not